# Parsing arguments in python returns empty line in terminal

Tags: python, parsing, terminal

I am unable to receive result in terminal while parsing arguments in python. Below script should work in a simple manner, one function multiplies components while other adds them. User is to choose by typing 1 or 2 which option should be applied.

```
import argparse

def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('first', type=int, nargs=1)
    parser.add_argument('second', type=int, nargs=1)
    parser.add_argument('decision' , type=int, nargs=1)

    return parser.parse_args()

def multiply(first, second):
    print(first * second)

def add(first, second):
    print(first + second)

args = parse_args()

if args.decision == 1:
    multiply(first, second)
elif args.decision == 2:
    add(first, second)
```

Thank you.

Comment: How do you invoke the script? What arguments do you pass? And please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `nargs=1` argument from your `add_argument(...)` calls. The default is a single argument, so it's unnecessary and not doing what you're expecting.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html?highlight=argparse#nargs) (emphasis mine):

> ArgumentParser objects **usually associate a single command-line argument with a single action** to be taken. The nargs keyword argument associates a different number of command-line arguments with a single action. The supported values are:
>
> N (an integer). N arguments from the command line will be gathered together into a list. For example:
>
> ... <snipped> ...
>
> Note that **nargs=1 produces a list of one item**. This is different from the default, in which the item is produced by itself.

Since `nargs=1` converts your argument into a list, `if args.decision == 1:` will never be true.

Also, you should be including `args.` in your function calls (i.e. doing `multiply(args.first, args.second)`, and similar for `add`).

Comment: What would be the proper way to use the value inside the list, other than indexing the first element of the list?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. You would have to index the list to get to the value (or unpack it into multiple variables), but removing `nargs` gets rid of the list entirely and just leaves the single int.